# RecyclerView Onclick (call non-static method)

Tags: java, android, static, onclick, android-recyclerview

I've got stuck with an issue about setting an OnItemClickListener to my RecyclerView items. I tried to set a listener the way described in the RecyclerView sample of Android Studio. So a listener is set in the ViewHolder class for my RecyclerView.

```
public class ProgramViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView vName;
    protected ImageView vProgramImage;

    public ProgramViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        vName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.programName);
        vProgramImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.programImage);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // HERE PROBLEM !! 
                MainActivity.openSettings(1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I want to call a method of my MainActivity openSettings(int ) to load a fragment:

```
public void openSettings(int layoutId) {
    settingsFragment setFrag = new settingsFragment();

    Bundle information = new Bundle();
    information.putInt("layoutId", layoutId);

    setFrag.setArguments(information);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, setFrag)
            .commit();
}
```

But now the problem. When I try to compile, it says "Non-static method 'openSettings(int )' cannot be referenced from a static context."
I quite not understand this error. Why is it a static context? The class ProgramViewHolder ist not declared static.

And the most important part: How can I fix it? I want to set a OnClickListener to every item of RecyclerView and call a public method of MainActivity.

Thanks a lot to you, for your time spending to help me.

Comment: MainActivity.this.openSettings(1) ?

Comment: why not move the open settings to the handler class?

Comment: Then it says, "'MainActivity' is not an enclosing class.

Comment: Well, I thought I need to get the FragmentManager from the MainActivity. As I understand I cannot call getFragmentManager() from the Adapter class..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not that ProgramViewHolder is static, it's because attempting to call your activity from a static context (you aren't calling a specific instance of the activity).

What you should do is pass the activity into your recyclerViewAdapter so that you have access to it.

For example

```
MainActivity mainActivity;
public CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}
```

And to create the recyclerViewAdapter from MainActivity

`CustomRecyclerView recyclerViewAdapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(this);
recyclerViewAdapter.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);`

You should then be able to access your method like this

`mainActivity.openSettings(1);`

Let me know if you have any trouble

//Edit

Here's how you would set onClick from bindViewHolder. You want to set up any onClickListeners here due to the way RecyclerView "recycles" data. For example, if each row should perform a different action on click, you need to make sure the click listener is tied to the specific row. Creating this in onBindViewHolder ensures this. If you want an entire row to be clickable, rather than elements inside, just create an outer view that fills the entire row. Then tie the onClickListener to that.

```
// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element

    ProgramViewHolder programViewHolder = (ProgramViewHolder) holder;
    programViewHolder.vName.setOnClicklistener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mainActivity.openSettings(1);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Ok, I got the problem. But I don't understand the solution. Where should I write the first snippet? My RecyclerView is created in a XML file. Isn't that better? How can I pass my instance of MainActivity?

Comment: I just edited the answer. I meant to tell you to pass the activity to the recyclerView adapter. I'm assuming you have an adapter for your recyclerView that contains your ProgramViewHolder?

Comment: Also, with RecyclerView, you shouldn't create an onClick listener from the ViewHolder. It should be created in onBindViewHolder. Please see this link to see how to properly create the adapter. https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: You mean I should set the OnClickListener to an specific view like vName or vProgramImage? What's the advantage of this? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

if you have `context` of the activity containing recyclerView, then you can simply do this:

```java
your_view_holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // HERE SOLUTION!! 
                ((MainActivity)context).openSettings(1);
            }
        });
```

You can place this in `onBindViewHolder(...)`

**How to get context:**

Create another parameter of context in your Adapter's constructor , and pass the context from your activity once instantiating Adapter .

**why pass the context:**

i would recommend you to always pass context and assign it to any adapter's variable because this is something you would require every now and then while working with your adapter, so instead of using a workaround every time for context, just save it once .